# How do you choose your database type based on the criteria (SQL, JSON, etc.) and how do you ensure its integrity?

Tags: android, sql, json, database, parsing

Implementing and managing remote or cloud databases in Android Applications is new to me. I am currently making an app that would take in thousands of "entries" to a form, think of it as an attendance app. Right now I've decided to use JSON as my database type and Parse as my BaaS. I need some tips on my decision.

1. I don't actually see JSON suitable for this because it is a "text" file that can easily be modified or if I somehow accidentally append an extra bracket it would render the whole database corrupt whereas SQL use queries like INSERT which I think is more secure. I just picked JSON because it works well with Parse. Do you think this is a good idea?
2. Another is what if the JSON file will accumulate tens of thousands of entries, how do you manage this huge database? Do you split it into several files (eg. every 1k entries make another JSON file) or is it enough to just dump all the data in that one JSON database file?
3. When using BaaS do you just sync the data in that server or do you also make backups of some sort (I don't really know how to put this)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON](http://json.org/) is **not** a database, but a data interchange format. You can have a database that uses JSON for communication, for internal representation, etc. but that does not make JSON a database in itself.

Parse itself manages the organization of the data. You communicate using JSON but don't have to care about how it's stored, updated, etc. internally.

So in your app, you should use SQLite for storing such amounts of information, or, depending on the app, just send it to the Parse server and execute the queries against it. You can see how it's done in the Parse Android [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide).

Comment: Well, as the database behind parse is MongoDB, it sort of is JSON, or rather BSON. But you are right, OP need not worry about it. By the way @slashred, you can (and should) based on you description, save your data to a file on parse. That is, you can create a column of type File and store any filetype, such as plain text. The amount of data you talk about would hit the limit of 128kb per object rather fast, but the file column can hold up to 10mb of data.

Comment: Oh, maybe disregard my comment about using File, think I may have misunderstood your question at first.

Comment: @Sebastian, I was really confused about this. I was even trying to search for things like appending and adding objects/entries in JSON and that is why I'm not getting proper answers. Anyway, got it now. Thanks for clearing it up!